# CartThrob CT Admin Timezone setting

Tags: cartthrob

I have recently taken over administration of a legacy EE (2.5.5) / CartThrob (2.1.4) site.  I've moved this successfully to a new server, and for the most part everything seems to be working.

The site has CT Admin installed (1.4.4).

The problem I'm having is that the CT Admin monthly report for the current month isn't working because the first order placed this month was at 00:15 on 1st June, and the CT Admin code is identifying this as 23:15 on 31st May.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I might do to fix this?  This is my first experience with EE, so I'm still getting to grips with it ...

Cheers,

Crac

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the localization settings inside of EE, and for the member you're logging in with specifically?

(Also note that CT Admin 1.4.4 and CT 2.1.4 are pretty old versions at this point and you may have better luck after upgrading).